# How can I remove value from a list based off it's location from a copy of that list?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to remove those specific items based off their location in the values list.
The below code, throws an error as the copy list shrinks too much

```
private ArrayList<String> removeGen(int addLines, int labLines, int venLines, ArrayList<String> values){
        ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
        copy = (ArrayList<String>) values.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 100 && i < (100 + (addLines * 5) + 1)) {
                copy.remove(i);
            }

            if (i > (100 + (addLines * 5)) + 9 && i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 10) {
                copy.remove(i);
            }

            if (i > 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 21 && i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + (venLines * 4) + 22) {
                copy.remove(i);
            }
        }

        return copy;
```

The problem is some values are indistinguishable from one another so I can't use remover(obj) either.

How can I return a list with the values removed at the above locations?

Comment: You should be able to remove entries like this, because you´re removeing something by its index and not by value.

Comment: Still the copy list reduces in size as its items are being removed making, their location change all good though check this out

Answer (score 1):

You´re deleting at an index and not by value, but you forgot that the index of `values` are other ones than the one in `copy` after you removed something.
Each object would get an other index after a remove and so the lists are not the same anymore.

Example:
After removing index 4 the index 5 is getting the new value on index 4. This switch-effect will go until the end of the list.

So there are two ways to make this one correct:

1. Turn your conditions around and add all valid data to `copy` and give this list back.
2. Null the value at index i and filter the list afterwards, before you return it. `return copy.filter(x -> x != null).collect(Collectors.toList());` 
   If you´re using java 7 and lower you can use `copy.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));`

Here the 1st result:

```
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    if (i < 100 && i > (100 + (addLines * 5) + 1)) {
        copy.add(values.get(i));
    }

    if (i < (100 + (addLines * 5)) + 9 && i > 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 10) {
        copy.add(values.get(i));
    }

    if (i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 21 && i > 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + (venLines * 4) + 22) {
        copy.add(values.get(i));
    }
}

return copy;
```

Here the 2nd result:

```
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
copy = (ArrayList<String>) values.clone();
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    if (i > 100 && i < (100 + (addLines * 5) + 1)) {
        copy.get(i) = null;
    }

    if (i > (100 + (addLines * 5)) + 9 && i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 10) {
        copy.get(i) = null;
    }

    if (i > 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 21 && i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + (venLines * 4) + 22) {
        copy.get(i) = null;
    }
}

return copy.filter(x -> x != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> removeGen(int addLines, int labLines, int venLines, ArrayList<String> values){
        ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        copy = (ArrayList<String>) values.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 100 && i < (100 + (addLines * 5) + 1)) {
                //copy.remove(i);
            }
            else if(i > (100 + (addLines * 5)) + 9 && i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 10) {
                //copy.remove(i);
            }

            else if(i > 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + 21 && i < 100 + (addLines * 5) + (labLines * 4) + (venLines * 4) + 22) {
                //copy.remove(i);
            }
            else {
                numbers.add(i);
            }


        }
        return numbers;

    }
```

Just did the opposite and extracted the locations i needed, should be helpful for others

```
 ArrayList<Integer> tempList = removeGen(additional,labour,vendor,values);

        for (int j = 0; j < tempList.size(); j++) {
            template = template.replaceFirst(section + j, values.get(tempList.get(j)));
        }
```